# .net 5 not seeding with data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

My app is not seeding data to databases in the controller.
It creates the database but it does not seed the data.

```
    [HttpGet("NewDb/{dbName}")]
    public void CreateNewDb(string dbName)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseMySql("server=localhost; user=username; password=password;database=" + dbName, 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));

        DataContext context = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        context.Database.Migrate(); 
         
        // where seed is not seeding the database.   
        Seed.SeedRoles(context, _roleManager);
      }
```

seed.cs
This is where the roles are created

```
  public static void SeedRoles(DataContext context, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
    {
        if (!context.Roles.Any())
        {
            //create roles
            var roles = new List<Role>
            {
                new Role{Name = "Admin"},
                new Role{Name = "Standard"}, 
                new Role{Name = "Basic"} 
            };
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Wait();                    
            }  
        }
                         
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your Seed class?

Comment: I've posted the seed class

Comment: is the roles backed by that table - if you want seeding ef core has built in seed support

Comment: You should never use .Wait() if you can help it. When you invoke a method that returns a Task or Task<T>, you should `await` that method. Which means SeedRoles needs to be marked as async and return a Task, and your CreateNewDb action method should be marked as async and return a Task and use `await` to call methods that return tasks like Seed.SeedRoles.

Comment: I created the seed class myself. How would I use the ef core seed in the CreateNewDb method?

Comment: its part of your model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding and lives in your migrations

Comment: Looks like for what you are looking to do, all you need to do is call `context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: I just tried adding context.SaveChangesAsync();, sadly it did not work. However, would I did add the seed in dataContext. I've added builder.Entity<UserRole>().HasData(), but how do i add the create method for creating the roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[HttpGet("NewDb/{dbName}")]
public async Task CreateNewDbAsync(string dbName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
        .UseMySql("server=localhost; user=username; password=password;database=" + dbName, 
        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));

    DataContext context = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    context.Database.Migrate(); 
     
    // where seed is not seeding the database.   
    Seed.SeedRolesAsync(context, _roleManager, cancellationToken);
  }
```

and this

```
public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(DataContext context, RoleManager<Role> roleManager, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (!context.Roles.Any())
    {
        //create roles
        var roles = new List<Role>
        {
            new Role{Name = "Admin"},
            new Role{Name = "Standard"}, 
            new Role{Name = "Basic"} 
        };
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            context.Add(role);
        }
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
                     
}
```

but what we do to seed data is in the Context we do the following. This will be called when you call `Migrate' on your database.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(Roles.Data);
}

public static class Roles
{
   // Here is where we stubb out our data
    public static List<Role> Data = new List<Role> {};
}
```

Comment: Replaced roleManaer with  context.Add(role) in the SeedRolesAsync method fixed it.